# how to install apache hue on top of apache hadoop in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hadoop, hue

Can anyone please suggest the references (or) share the idea regarding installation steps of apache hue on top of apache hadoop 2.6.1

Comment: Can anyone please help me out regarding installation part of hue

Comment: It is just detailed here: http://gethue.com/how-to-build-hue-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/ (14 and 12 are the same, except 1 or 2 package names slightly different)